# One word for "putting it together"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am starting a blog focused on software development and trying to come up with some catchy name for it.
The theme of the blog should be "putting things together", or to "connect all dots of complex programming problems".

Is there a one word or a simple phrase that would mean the same thing? I was thinking about words like "fusion" or "link", but the resulting names (codefusion, codelinking, codelinker) don't feel right somehow.

Comment: Choose [any one you like](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf).

Comment: Codefusion won't feel right b/c it's already the name of a company. Anything with 'link' in it already has specific connotations. So perhaps you need to be a bit more abstract - try to find a word from another field that has a similar meaning . . ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invent your own word! Perhaps something like "codecatenate" or "codecatenation"

A deliberate play on the word *concatenate*, which seems to have the exact meaning you desire.  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concatenate

Answer (score 4):

**Assemble** *(verb)* - fit together the separate component parts of (a machine or other object).
   *Alternate forms:* **assembly** *(noun)*, **assembling** *(verb)*

I like the sound *"Code Assembly"*, *"Code Assembler"*, or *"Assembling Code"*, but you do risk being mistaken for being a blog about [Assembly Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language).

Comment: Where are those citations from? Please tell us the name of where you got those from, and if applicable, also a link. If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 2):

Synthesis?

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/synthesis

> the combining of the constituent elements of separate material or abstract entities into a single or unified entity (opposed to analysis, ) the separating of any material or abstract entity into its constituent elements.

Answer (score 1):

These words basically mean "a lot of things coming together to form one thing":

[Syncrasy](http://www.whatdoesthatmean.com/dictionary/S/syncrasy.html): (Noun) Combination of many things.

[Coadunate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coadunate): (Adjective) Combine into one.

[Inosculate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inosculate): (Verb) Combine into one.

Comment: @tchrist The links I provided aren't the source of the information. The links provided are for further reading. The words that you see here are from my brain as I know them from reading books. That's the source. The links are just to back up my claims.

Answer (score 1):

For linked:

**Syndetic**: 
    [adjective Etymology: Greek syndetikos, from syndein to bind together — more at asyndeton Date: 1876 connective, connecting](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mwc/60543/syndetic)

**Isoline**: [(ī′sə-līn′)
n.
A line on a map, chart, or graph connecting points of equal value. Also called isogram.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/isoline)

For fusion:

[Amalgamate](http://www.realdictionary.com/?q=amalgamate)

Comment: smart thinking.

Comment: If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 1):

There is "nexus", meaning a series of connections between one thing and another. There is also "plexus", which is the same thing, but in the form of a mesh or net, or a criss-cross pattern of any sort. If you're looking for a catchy title, you might put both words together and call it Nexus Plexus.

Answer (score 0):

*Network or tie-in* comes to my mind .

What about: *code-combining* , *code-solving* or *code-solution*

Answer (score 0):

here is a word:

Collate - Collect and combine (texts, information, or data)

you could form a cool name such as "code collation" or "code collating".